# input output in prolog

Tags: list, file-io, prolog

i want to read characters from a file in prolog and place them in a list.
could some one help me out with it?
thanks

Comment: Sure! Just show us what you've done so far and someone will be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWI-Prolog offers `read_file_to_codes/3`. Usage example:

```
?- read_file_to_codes('/etc/passwd', Codes, []).
Codes = [114, 111, 111, 116, 58, 120, 58, 48, 58|...].
```